# Is there a way to find matching folder names and change the last modified date?

Tags: powershell

I copied several folders from server A to server B.  The last modified date of the folders have changed to today's date and I would like to get the original last modified date to change to the original last modified date on all folders.  I have a backup of the old folder structures with the correct last modified date.  Is there a way I can run a powershell script to find all folders with the same names and change the NewFolder last modified to to the Old Folder last modified date?

I used the code below to manually change 1 folders last modified date but I have several hundreds of folders that would need to be updated.

```
$folder = Get-Item "C:\New folder\New folder"
$folder.LastWriteTime = '01/11/2005 06:01:36'
```

I would like to see NewFolderA last modified date be the same as OldFolderA last modified date.

Comment: robocopy has a `/DCOPY:T :: COPY Directory Timestamps` option. that is likely the best AND fastest way to do it. [*grin*]

Comment: That will do it.  I just added /E *.* to exclude copying files.

Comment: kool! glad to know it worked as you needed ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Dr.Prog The parameter `/e` includes empty subfolders. It does not exclude files. For the latter you need `/xf *.*`.